# How to get parameters list of a function covered by a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, inspect

I get function parameters list in this way:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    # do something
    return

print inspect.getargspec(foo)
```

Output is:

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

But if the target function has a decorator, the results will be changed:

```
def dec_func(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        # do something
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

@dec_func
def foo(a, b, c):
    # do something
    return

print inspect.getargspec(foo)
```

Now the output is:

```
ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

We can see, the info is about the wrapper in dec_func, not foo I want.

Any idea about how to still get info of foo?

Btw, why I ask it: Suppose I have a function A, and in some other codes I get the parameter list of function A to check/do something. This system will be broken if I add decorators to A, e.g. @numba.jit or @profile...

The solution is found: https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def dec_func(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        # do something
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

@dec_func
def foo(a, b, c):
    # do something
    return

print inspect.getargspec(foo)
```

The output is:

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: You will need to apply `functools.wraps` to `wrapper` as the name `foo` is actually pointing to the `wrapper` object.

Comment: I added the func.wraps to wrapper func, now if I print foo.__name__, the result is 'foo', but the result of inspect.getargsspec(foo) is still showing info of wrapper

Comment: Oh, I found the solution based on the key words you given!
Just need to add @decorator to the dec_func

Comment: @Rocky.L: So write an answer?

Comment: The answer is at the bottom of this site: https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/